# Ember dynamic routing not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I want to have a url like this `/restaurants/:pageNumber` and I want `/restaurants` to assume the pageNumber parameter is 1.

Here is my `Router.js` :

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('restaurants', function() {});
  this.route('restaurants', { path: '/restaurants/:pageNumber' }, function() {});
});
```

If it remove the `function() {}` for it, I just get a blank page with no errors in the console for `/restaurants/1`

My `routes/restaurants/index.js` :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      response: this.get('ajax').request('/getAllRestaurants', {method: 'GET'}),
      currentPage: params.pageNumber | 1
    });
  }
});
```

On the `templates/restaurants/index.hbs` I check `{{model.currentPage}}` and it's always `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `{ path: '/restaurants/:page_number' }` and

`currentPage: params.page_number || 1` ?

Comment: The name of dynamic segment is in model-name_property  instead of modelProperty (camelCase). It is convention. see: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments

Answer (score 0):

Because logical OR is ||, not |. `page = params.pageNumber  || 1`. But more reliable is ternary operator, `page = (params.pageNumber !== undefined ? params.pageNumber : 1)`